# What is the probability of finding the possible passwords if the first 5 digits of the SHA-1 hashed value is known?

Tags: security, sha1, password-protection, sha

happened to read about a service that checks a password against commonly used / breached ones.

https://www.troyhunt.com/ive-just-launched-pwned-passwords-version-2/

A given password is hashed (SHA-1) and then the first 5 characters of the hash is compared against the commonly used ones. This service is exposed via API. This could mean that the first 5 digits of the hash is exposed to the outside world. Isn't that a risk the API users are taking?
What is the probability of finding the possible passwords (eg: rainbow tables) if the first 5 digits of the SHA-1 hashed value is known?

Also if we don't find a matching record - that indicates that the password is not in the list of pwned set. Isn't that a clue that the password is outside this set?

Comment: Well, the some 'obvious' problems are using SHA-1 (it's too fast for secrets, regardless of other issues) and not using salt and/or stretching (which defeat rainbow tables) .. :}

Comment: Anyway, SHA-1 minus 5 hex digits is still 35 hex digits, or 16^35 values ~ 1.3937966e+42 ~ "139 x (10 followed by 40 zeros)" ~ still a very large space.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you've asked (and why the first comment in response to your question isn't relevant) is either answered in the blog post you linked to or in the ensuing discussion in the comments. In short:

The first 5 chars means there are 16^35 different possible suffixes. The total possible values the original password *could* be is infinite.

You could make an argument that the law of probability dictates the underlying password is more likely to be one already in HIBP and in there with a higher prevalence count, but from the hash prefix alone you have absolutely nothing to verify that assumption.

And even if you *could* reliably guess the actual password, there's no context of the username it's associated to. Depending on how it's queried, there may also be no context as to which service is checking the API hence no information about where the password is actually used.

And if you're still paranoid after all that, just download the hashes and use them locally

Comment: keeping the hashes local - that was what I was also thinking.. That would reduce those risks.

Might be interesting to find how many of the hashes has the first 5 digits common in the set. If there is a match found, there is a chance that people may just add/modify the first password slightly and use. may be we should warn the user there as well.